# Can anyone help me how to access a data from an fla file to another fla file?

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone help me how to access a data from an fla file to another fla file?

I have a starting fla file called "savescore.fla" which is connected to the class called "score.as".I have a "btnAdd" button that if clicked, it will add by one to the variable "scoring" in the class "score.as". I have also a movieclip "btnSave" that would save the score. Lastly, I have a "next_btn" button that would go directly to my another fla file 
which is "finalscore.fla". I wanted the "finalscore.fla" to show the current "scoring" variable from the "score.as" class but the problem is that it will only show 0/zero as the score. I think that as "savescore.fla" saves and edits the variable in the "score.as", it will only make changes to itself and not to the "score.as" that's why I still got 0 as the final score because it comes from the "score.as" and not from "savescore.fla". So I was thinking if I could just access the score from the "savescore.fla", it would solve the problem. But I have no idea what codes to put...or can you give me another way?

Here are the codes: (Btw, I am using actionscript 3.0)

**savescore.fla:**

```
var lol:score = new score();

var saveDataObject:SharedObject;
//var currentScore:int;

init(); // this line goes directly beneath the variables

function init():void{ // call once to set everything up

     saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test"); // give the save data a location

     btnAdd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addScore); // clicking on +1
     btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveData); // clicking on Save
 next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sunod); // clicking on +1

 if(saveDataObject.data.savedScore == null){ // checks if there is save data
      trace("No saved data yet."); // if there isn't any data on the computer...
      saveDataObject.data.savedScore = lol.scoring; // ...set the savedScore to 0

 } else {
      trace("Save data found."); // if we did find data...
      loadData(); // ...load the data
 }

 }


function addScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
     lol.scoring+=1; // add 1 to the score
}

function saveData(e:MouseEvent):void{
     saveDataObject.data.savedScore = lol.scoring; // set the saved score to the current      score
 trace("Data Saved!");
 saveDataObject.flush(); // immediately save to the local drive

 trace(saveDataObject.size); // this will show the size of the save file, in bytes
 trace(lol.GetFullScore());
}

function loadData():void{
     lol.scoring = saveDataObject.data.savedScore; // set the current score to the saved score

 trace("Data Loaded!");
}

function sunod(event:MouseEvent):void{

var ldr:Loader=new Loader();
ldr.load(new URLRequest("finalscore.swf"));
addChild(ldr);
}
```

**score.as:**

```
package{


public class score{

    public var scoring:int;



    function score()
    {

    }





public function SetScore(val:int):void 
{ 
  scoring = val;
} 





public function GetFullScore():int 
{ 
  return scoring;
  trace(scoring);
}


    }
}
```

**finalscore.fla:**

```
var lol1:score = new score();

txtScore.text = ("Score: " + lol1.GetFullScore()); // set the text property of the    txtScore


trace(lol1.GetFullScore());
```

Comment: so are you wanting to send variables from one swf to another?

Comment: Yes..That's exactly what I wanted to do since I can't save the changes in my "score.as" class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have loaded an external swf you can grab a reference to it in an onLoadedHandler. So in savescore:

```
var myReference:Object;

function loadComplete(event:Event):void {

    myReference= event.target.content;

        myReference.lol1.GetFullScore();
... or...
       var myScore = event.target.lol1.GetFullScore();
 etc...

}
```

you'll want to make sure the reference exists before you use it

**EDIT**

in your Child SWF create a variable and method to store the parent:

```
var parentSWF:MovieClip;


function setParent(myParent:MovieClip):void{
    parentSWF = myParent;
}
```

then in the parent send the child a reference :

```
function loadComplete(event:Event):void {

    myReference= event.target.content;

        // use the reference to child to call
        // any variables or functions in it
        myReference.lol1.GetFullScore();

        // set the reference in child with the following
        // so that the child can call the parent
        myReference.setParent(this);

}
```

then in child you can use lol :

```
 parentSWF.lol;
```

If you had to go this way you would ideally create measures to check the objects/methods etc exist before they are used

**FINAL EDIT**

For a start, move

```
var ldr:Loader=new Loader();
```

out of the sunod function and put it at the top with the other declaration so that loadcomplete can use it. You need to set up a listener for the loadComplete handler. Put this after your other listeners

```
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
```

in your loadcomplete handler in savescore add

```
   myReference.doThisWhenLoaded();
```

in finalscore put

```
function doThisWhenLoaded():void{
    txtScore.text = ("Score: " + parentSWF.lol);


}
```

This just seems complete overkill and I'm sure I've overcomplicated your over complications(!). My advice would be to do away with the second swf and just create a finalscore.as object in savescore. This would be so much easier. At the moment I can't see why you want to have another swf floating around. I've never been a fan of multiple swfs though so someone else may well jump in and correct this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but what do I put in "finalscore.fla" in order to access the data from "savescore.fla"?

Comment: What you are trying to do seems quite akward. Why don't you create a class instead of a new swf? If you want to do it with multiple swfs you can pass a reference of the parent to the child..see my edit

Comment: I just tried your "EDIT"..(I decided to use multiple swfs) but I get an error in my "finalscore.fla" saying "cannot access a null object reference...etc." and I think it's because of the parentSWF.lol...am I using the codes properly? sorry for the trouble...I'm really good in actionscript..

Comment: These are my codes with few changes..I just added your code..I didn't make any changes in "score.as"

Comment: Sorry for my comment above: I really meant "I'm not really good in actionscript"..

Comment: Since I can't type all my codes,I'll just tell you what I've done: in "savescore.fla", I added this:    `function loadComplete(event:Event):void {     myReference= event.target.content;     myReference.lol1.GetFullScore();     myReference.setParent(this); }` in my "finalscore.fla", these are my codes:     `var lol1:score = new score();     var parentSWF:MovieClip;     function setParent(myParent:MovieClip):void{     parentSWF = myParent; }     txtScore.text = ("Score: " + parentSWF.lol); // set the text property of the txtScore`

Comment: if you can post the whole thing somewhere I'll have a look. That error occurs when you try and reference somethng that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I can't type all the codes in the comment box...Can you teach me how to do it just like what you did in your comment above where you were able to comment your codes?

Comment: By the way, I just add your function "loadComplete" into my "savescore.fla" and the variable "parentSWF" & function "setParent" into my "finalscore.fla"...then I replaced my:    `txtScore.text = ("Score: " + lol1.GetFullScore()); ` with `txtScore.text = ("Score: " + parentSWF.lol);`

Comment: I just meant find a file sharing service where I can download all the files you're using. You can also edit your first post

Comment: Thanks..I really appreciate your reply..if I can't pull this through, I'll be giving up this method and maybe start by using your advise..

Comment: I am trying to make an educational game which composed of multiple games..I am planning to have an swf for every game that's why I came up with the idea which may not be a good idea after all..any possible method to this one?

Comment: If you do it with multiple SWFs it would be a good idea to read up on using multiple swfs. I would google it and really get your head around it. I would start with help from Adobe http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/load-external-swf-swf.html then move on to some other resources. Plan it out on paper how each swf will need to talk to the other. If each of your child SWFs need to talk to the parent. I would make each SWF standalone then create a globalScore object in your parent and pass a reference to it to each child SWF that each child can then access/read/amend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the changes of my code:

**savescore.fla:**

```
var lol:score = new score();

var saveDataObject:SharedObject;

init(); // this line goes directly beneath the variables

function init():void{ // call once to set everything up

 saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test"); // give the save data a location

 btnAdd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addScore); // clicking on +1
 btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveData); // clicking on Save
 next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sunod); // clicking on +1

 if(saveDataObject.data.savedScore == null){ // checks if there is save data
      trace("No saved data yet."); // if there isn't any data on the computer...
      saveDataObject.data.savedScore = lol.scoring; // ...set the savedScore to 0

 } else {
      trace("Save data found."); // if we did find data...
      loadData(); // ...load the data
 }

}


function addScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
     lol.scoring+=1; // add 1 to the score
}

function saveData(e:MouseEvent):void{
     saveDataObject.data.savedScore = lol.scoring; // set the saved score to the current      score
     trace("Data Saved!");
     saveDataObject.flush(); // immediately save to the local drive

     trace(saveDataObject.size); // this will show the size of the save file, in bytes
     trace(lol.GetFullScore());
}

function loadData():void{
     lol.scoring = saveDataObject.data.savedScore; // set the current score to the saved score
     trace("Data Loaded!");
}

function sunod(event:MouseEvent):void{

var ldr:Loader=new Loader();
ldr.load(new URLRequest("finalscore.swf"));
addChild(ldr);
}

var myReference:Object;


function loadComplete(event:Event):void {

    myReference= event.target.content;

    myReference.lol1.GetFullScore();

    myReference.setParent(this);

}
```

**finalscore.fla:**

```
var lol1:score = new score();
var parentSWF:MovieClip;

txtScore.text = ("Score: " + parentSWF.lol); // this line has the error because of parentSWF.lol

trace(lol1.GetFullScore());

function setParent(myParent:MovieClip):void{
    parentSWF = myParent;
}
```

**score.as:**

```
package{

public class score{

    public var scoring:int;

    function score()
    {

    }


public function SetScore(val:int):void 
{ 
  scoring = val;
} 


public function GetFullScore():int 
{ 
  return scoring;
  trace(scoring);
}

 }
}
```